# socket.io client listening to same event multiple times after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I got a master page which contains a table of items and the table data will be refreshed continuously after a successful `socket.io` connection with the server.

upon clicking an item in the table (id of the item will be passed to the server), a child view will be loaded using ajax and that will be refreshed continuously by listening to an event from the server.

Now the problem is, by selecting another item in the table, the child view is listening multiple times(even though I clear the child view (HTML) after successful ajax operation). For example, if you select 10 items, it listens 10 times and can't see whats happening in the child view (everything is blinking very fast).

#### app.js (nodejs)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client Connected...' + clients[socket.id]);
    // updates master page table.
    socket.emit('data', self.StatusObject(self.allModules));

    socket.on('close', function (err, res) {
        console.log('Client disconnected...' + err + ' ' + res);
    });

    //updates child view.
    socket.on('childData', function (id) {
        var data = self.FindModule(id);
        statusPacketTimer = setInterval(function () {
            socket.emit('publishChildData', self.StatusPacket(id));
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

#### masterpage.html (html & jquery)

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="getContent(${id})">
        <td>row_id</td>
        <td>status</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
socket.on('data', function (message) {
    $('#mainTable').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
    updateTable(message);
});

function getContent(id) {
if (id){
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            url: 'getContext',
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (data, status, moduleData) {
                if (status == 'success') {
                    $('#content').html('').html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

#### childpage.html(html & jquery)

```
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    socket.emit('childData', $('#id').val());
    socket.on('publishChildData', function (data) {
        // replace the data in div with new data
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//updates child view.
socket.on('childData', function (id) {
    var data = self.FindModule(id);
    statusPacketTimer = setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('moduleData', self.LocateStatusPacket(id));
    }, 1000);
});
```

in this code the `setInterval` continous.
if the child view rendering is triggered via `socket.emit('moduleData', self.LocateStatusPacket(id));`

then it is rendering every second

Comment: sorry my mistake ,small change in code, review it again. @kiro112

Comment: @zzzziiiirrrrkkkkkkkk it is still the same. why do you use `setInterval` ? is it for a delay or for continous update ?

Comment: because I need some live information to be transferred all the time to child view based on the item selected in master page table.
if another item selected in table, then information regarding that child view should be transferred.

Is there any better solution for that instead of setInterval.

Comment: im not currently sure how you implemented it. but i think the issue here is your are rendering the child view multiple times because of the `setInterval`. maybe remove the setInterval and trigger an update when there is a changes on the currently selected item

Comment: no child view will be rendered only once using the ajax operation in master page. but the data inside that child view will be updated by socket.io event listener multiple times in a second (for the number of times you click in master page).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Before each instance of `socket.on(endpoint, callback)`, precede it with `socket.off(endpoint, callback)`.

```
<script>
    const dataCallback = function (message) {
        $('#mainTable').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
        cupdateTable(message);
    };
    socket.off('data', dataCallback); // Removes existing handler, if present.
    socket.on('data', dataCallback);
</script>
```

This removes only the `dataCallback` callback from the `data` endpoint. If you want to delete all callback functions associated with the `data` endpoint (it's perfectly legal to have more than one), then you can omit the callback argument and simply do

```
<script>
    const dataCallback = function (message) {
        $('#mainTable').find('tr:gt(0)').remove();
        cupdateTable(message);
    };
    socket.off('data'); // Removes ALL existing handlers for this endpoint.
    socket.on('data', dataCallback);
</script>
```