# Send continuous updates to connected clients using socket.io and nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

Can anyone tell me how to send continuous updates to connected clients every second using nodejs and socket.io?

NOTE: I don't want to use the setInterval() function as it is unfit for my current scenario.

Comment: are you looking for this https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/?

Comment: can you post your current server file?

Comment: You say, "Every few seconds", but that you don't want to use `setInterval()`.  How else do you propose to trigger an action on your server every few seconds - that's what `setInterval()` is for unless you have some other event driven mechanism you wish to use that you should tell us about.  This problem seems overly constrained without explaining any rationale.

Comment: On the server you use `io.emit(someEventName, data)` to send a socket.io message to all currently connected clients.  How you trigger that and how often you trigger that depends upon a given application and what you're trying to do (which you have not shared with us at all).

Comment: let take an example of location tracking when a user connect to server
step 1: **server side** io.emit('sendlatLong')

step2: **in client** side they get it in a io.on('sendlatLong') block and just after receiving it they will io.emit with latLong.

step3: **in server side** you will have a io.on block where you will get the emitted lat long from client and just after receiving it you will again send io.emit('sendLatLong') 

step4:so now you have created a loop like. so no need to use interval.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972724/socket-io-client-listening-to-same-event-multiple-times-after-refresh, thats the reason I don't want to use setInterval() function. Is there any better solution for the problem shown up there.

Comment: We can't help you until you show your code and we can see exactly what you're trying to do.  There is no generic alternative to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` to do something repeatedly.  The only other way would involved responding to some sort of event that occurs in your system, but you've shown us NO code whatsoever so we have no idea about that.  This question, as shown now, is unanswerable and should probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `setTimeout` in a function that references itself in the `setTimeout`. Basically the same result as doing `setInterval` but will always wait for the function to finish (assuming synchronous code) before running the timeout function again.

```
function thingToRepeat() {
  let shouldCancel = false;
  // send messages, do stuff, 
  // set shouldCancel to true to stop looping if needed

  if (!shouldCancel) {
    setTimeout(thingToRepeat, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is really not much different than using `setInterval()`.  It seems more interesting to figure out why the OP forbids using a timer.

Comment: The difference is in when it'll run. The above code will run every 1000ms + the time it takes the intervening code to run, while `setInterval` runs exactly every 1000ms, regardless of how long the code in the resulting function takes. There are valid reasons to use either one, I'm not sure why the OP doesn't allow setInterval, but the timing difference could be it.